# TSQL Simple Regex Matching

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql

I need to check if a variable is a value 10.00 through 10.09. How can I do this by regex ?

```
IF SomeRegExFunction(@var, '10.0*')
    print 'It worked'
```

Is there some way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Should `10.0` match? It is of course mathematically the same as `10.00`

Comment: Yes it should. I am working with some code of some items and these strings are stored like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
declare @var as varchar(10)
set @var = '11.07'

if @var like '10.0[0-9]'
    print 'It worked'
else
    print 'not a match'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/5956)

Comment: Doesn't match `10.0` though which you said you wanted.

Comment: @MartinSmith I apologize, I made a mistake in that comment. I actually meant that 10.0 should not match. I was thinking of something else. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server's `like` as a simple expression syntax:

```
if @var like '10.0[0-9]' or @var = '10.0'
    print 'Hello World!'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about [PATINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx). I think that you are looking for something like this.

Comment: I don't think this is what I need. I do not have to find the a string from within an expression